# How can I POST an object array with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Is this even possible?  I've been searching and reading for hours and 99% of the posts are about JSON. I just have an object array I want to POST, nothing special.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({"name":"steve", "age":35});
arr.push({"name":"sam", "age": 25});
```

on the other end (node.js), I get this:

```
{ steve: '', sam: '' }
```

I'd be incredibly happy to get something similar to

```
[{"name":"steve", "age":35},
{"name":"sam", "age": 25}]
```

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly simple, because this seems trivial.  I'm not constructing the array myself and this is the format I receive it in.  I figured it would be something I could just throw into an $.ajax() post and grab it on the other side.

I've tried so many different combinations of the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: theArray,
    url: someAddress
})
```

with type instead of method, contentType, dataType, etc, etc with no luck.  Spent a whole bunch of time on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ but everyone wants to send JSON.  I tried JSON.stringify() on the client, but JSON.parse()on the server side results in giving me data just like my "on the other end..." example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "testcookie.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'arr[]': JSON.stringify(arr)
        }
    });
```

Comment: using `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', data: { 'arr': JSON.stringify(arr) }, url: 'http://localhost:3000/people/new' })` gets it through.  `var d = JSON.parse(req.body.arr); console.log(d[0].name);` outputs _steve_.  Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You should use like so data is sent as json string.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(theArray),
    content type:" application/json",
    url: someAddress
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I was posting from my mobile, so hard to do formatting

Answer (score 1):

A post request is expected to be a key-value pair.
If you give your array a key:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({"myArray": theArray}),
  url: someAddress
})
```

You should be able to retrieve it from the Post body 'myArray' key on the other side.

Comment: node.js receives it as _{ '{"myArray":[{"name":"steve","age":35},{"name":"sam","age":25}]}': '' }_ req.body.myArray = undefined, req.body[0] = undefined, req.body['myArray'] = undefined, JSON.parse(req.body) gives a SyntaxError.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Node.js should receive it as a string `'{"myArray":[{"name":"steve","age":35},{"name":"sam","age":25}]}'` Which you then convert into an object: `var theObject = JSON.parse(data);` Then you should be able to use it with `theObject.myArray`.

Comment: `$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"myArray": theArray}),
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/people/new'
    })`

Comment: Try without the JSON.stringify (and remove the `;` after the url).

Answer (score 0):

Convert that object to a String using `String()` function or use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: String(theArray),
    url: someAddress
});
```

Comment: Using this gives me an output on the server side as `{ '[object Object],[object Object]': '' }`